# SQLException when running Oracle SQL Stored Procedure in JPA

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, sqlexception

Running my query in this way

```
this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("{ ? = call do_build() }").getResultList()
```

is throwing the exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2452)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1832)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:179)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:241)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1752)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3444)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3493)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1869)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:718)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax?? I've tried many other forms and haven't been able to find the right format.

-- EDIT --

Stored Procedure:

```
PROCEDURE        do_build AS
  version_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
-- selects/truncates/inserts/etc.
END do_build;
```

Comment: If it is really a procedure, why are you trying to assign a return value - shouldn't it be `"{ call do_build() }"`? And what would `getResultList()` do if there is nothing returned? (I don't use `jpa` so I'm not qualified to say how it's supposed to look, but this doesn't look right to me; is there just an `execute` option for the query object?)

Comment: it's my understanding that at least a boolean is returned to indicate whether the stored procedure succeeded or not and I've never seen format without a return type but it could be,.. I believe there's an executeUpdate but this is not an update, and there's no just execute so I'm not sure how to only run the query with no return

Comment: The `executeQuery` will return a boolean, but the Oracle procedure itself does not. A procedure doesn't return anything (but can have `out` parameters, which is different). [This wiki entry](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Stored_Procedures) has examples, depending on your version. That shows the `begin`/`end` syntax rather than `call` but you can use either as far as the driver is concerned.